# pandoc filter returns list of words for a string

Tags: pandoc

I have a markdown file with a header line `# Foo Bar Baz`
When I run `pandoc /tmp/test.md -s -t native` I get

```
[Header 1 ("foo-bar-baz",[],[]) [Str "Foo",Space,Str "Bar",Space,Str "Baz"]
```

Is there any specific reason pandoc splits the line into individual words instead of returning one single string? What is the best way to get one line per formatting?

I am trying to write a filter which applies a regular expression per header, is It ok if I just join the words and return a single string? or am I also required to return a similar list of words?